# Replay a screen log file incrementally

Tags: terminal, logs, gnu-screen, tty

I have run some commands in gnu screen and used the `C-a H` command to record the output to a `screenlog.0` file. However now I want to view it. There are loads of terminal escape sequences, so just `cat`-ing it will show me everything all at once.

I know there is no timing informating in this file, and that's fine. But is it possible to some how incrementally reply the file? One character/escape sequence at a time? Is there any command that will take a file like this and only "print" each character/escape sequence one at a time while I press buttons / allow me to step ahead?

**UPDATE**: If I use `less` or `more`, I can see the file and see things, but that shows me the raw contents, including control codes. If I half entered a command and pressed <kbd>tab</kbd>, it shows the tab key. So I can't copy/paste

Answer (score 3):

You could use a pager like `less` or `more`:

```
less screenlog.0
```

Or

```
more screenlog.0
```

Not sure what terminal escape codes you have but if they are not displayed correctly, use

```
less -R screenlog.0
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. I edited your answer to make it more informative. We like answers to explain how a suggested tool would be used to solve the issue described.

Comment: less & more do allow you to see the file, which is OK, but not exactly what I want. `less` shows me all the escape codes, so I can't copy paste in or out of the file

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple POC Bash script to replay `screenlog.0` while one can change the replay speed by pressing <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, ... <kbd>9</kbd> where 0 means full speed. Press <kbd>space</kbd> to pause/resume.

```bsh
exec 6< screenlog.0
sleep=2 # initial speed where 2 means 0.2s pauses between "lines"
while read -r line <&6 ; do
  printf '%b\n' "$line"
  read -s -N 1 -t .$sleep
  case "$REPLY" in [0-9]) sleep="$REPLY";; " ") read -s -d " ";; esac
done
```